# How can one catch exceptions in python PubSub subscriber that are happening in internal/library threads?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm running pubsub consumers that process incoming messages at a rate of around one per second.  Things generally work fine, however, every few days or hours we occasionally see exceptions thrown by threads internal to the pubsub modules, and it's not clear to me how to catch them.  Here's a typical example (other similar traces with slightly different messages also occur):

```
Exception in thread Thread-LeaseMaintainer:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 549, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 466, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1554568036.075280756","description":"channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2294,"grpc_status":14}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 179, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/leaser.py", line 146, in maintain_leases
    [requests.ModAckRequest(ack_id, p99) for ack_id in ack_ids]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/dispatcher.py", line 152, in modify_ack_deadline
    self._manager.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 268, in send
    self._send_unary_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 259, in _send_unary_request
    ack_deadline_seconds=deadline,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/_gapic.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    fx = lambda self, *a, **kw: wrapped_fx(self.api, *a, **kw)  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/subscriber_client.py", line 723, in modify_ack_deadline
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 270, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 199, in retry_target
    last_exc,
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(<function _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable at 0x7f86228cd400>, subscription: "projects/xxxxx-dev/subscriptions/telemetry-sub"
ack_deadline_seconds: 10
ack_ids: "QBJMJwFESVMrQwsqWBFOBCEhPjA-RVNEUAYWLF1GSFE3GQhoUQ5PXiM_NSAoRRoHIGoKOUJdEmJoXFx1B1ALEHQoYnxvWRYFCEdReF1YHQdodGxXOFUEHnN1Y3xtWhQDAEFXf3f8gIrJ38BtZho9WxJLLD5-LDRFQV4"
, metadata=[('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.6.8 grpc/1.19.0 gax/1.8.2 gapic/0.40.0')]), last exception: 503 channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE

Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream caught unexpected exception Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(<function _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable at 0x7f86228cda60>, subscription: "projects/xxxxx-dev/subscriptions/telemetry-sub"
ack_deadline_seconds: 10
ack_ids: "QBJMJwFESVMrQwsqWBFOBCEhPjA-RVNEUAYWLF1GSFE3GQhoUQ5PXiM_NSAoRRoHIGoKOUJdEmJoXFx1B1ALEHQoYnxvWRYFCEdReF1YHAdodGxXOFUEHnN1aXVoWxAIBEdXeXf8gIrJ38BtZho9WxJLLD5-LDRFQV4"
, metadata=[('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.6.8 grpc/1.19.0 gax/1.8.2 gapic/0.40.0')]), last exception: 503 channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE and will exit.
```

(In this particular case, the subscriber received several similar errors and stopped consuming messages altogether (without the main thread exiting); though, other behavior has been observed in the case of other such library errors.)

Our code looks roughly like this (with some simplification):

```
client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=500)
future = client.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback, 
     flow_control=flow_control)
...
    try:
        future.result(timeout=1)
    except pubsub_v1.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        pass
    except _Rendezvous as exc:
        logger.error('Got Rendezvous error in subscriber. Retrying in 1s. '
                     f'Detail: {exc}')
        # NEVER GET HERE
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    except RetryError as exc:
        logger.error('Got RetryError in subscriber. Retrying in 1s. '
                     f'Detail: {exc}')
        # NEVER GET HERE
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    except Exception as exc:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
        logger.exception('Got uncaught exception in subscriber or callback ...')
        # NEVER GET HERE
```

None of the exception branches are ever taken. That leads me to think that the exception is happening in some background thread and is not reported by the future.result() call, in spite of the documentation ([GCP PubSub Docs](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub/subscriber/)) to the contrary.  I've read a number of github issues, perused the documentation, and scoured SO questions related to this, but I have been unable to find a solution that actually catches such errors.  Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Versions:

- python == 3.6.5
- google-cloud-pubsub == 0.40.0  # but this has behaved
  similarly for at least the last several versions
- google-api-core == 1.8.2
- google-api-python-client == 1.7.8

Comment: Having the same issue but with Publisher. Have you found the solution?

Comment: For this specific error, our application gets rebooted automatically (we wrote a second thread that monitors for no received messages in N minutes). So, I can't confirm that we'd see the behavior you are, medvedev; but, no, we haven't gotten an answer yet and I plan to open a ticket with GCP within a couple days if nothing useful gets posted here.  Good luck to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to catch these internal errors and handle them. They are transient errors in the library's connection to the Google Cloud Pub/Sub service and the library itself should handle them. If it does not--and in particular if it prevents further messages from being received without restarting, then it is a bug and an issue should be entered in the [GitHub repo for the Python client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues).

Comment: Thanks. With this particular exception, it did halt the subscriber callback processing without the future.result() raising an exception; and it happened more than once.  As for just ignoring these errors, the issue is that we run our code in GKE and rely on Stackdriver error reporting; so, the fact that these get printed to stderr and raised in some fashion leads them to generate Stackdriver error event notifications (and, of course, logs), both of which we'd prefer to avoid if the issues are transient and recoverable.

Comment: Yes, it would hopefully be the case that for transient exceptions, the client library would catch them, handle them, and not print out the errors at all (unless debug logging is turned on to help track down a problem within the library itself). These transient issues are expected to happen and one of the goals of the client library is to take care of these details for you.

Comment: I have opened up [issue #7709](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7709) for this problem.

Comment: Update: A [fix](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/7863) for this issue has been merged. It makes sure that a `RetryError` is propagated to the main thread, and that a clean shutdown of background threads is initiated. At the time of writing, the fix has not been released yet, though.

Comment: This issue still exists in google-cloud-pubsub==2.14.1.
and I am not able to find the solution.